# Python Optimization Problem - Minimize number of groups needed to satisfy requirements of another variable

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to correctly understand an optimization problem using PuLP, however, I'm having a hard time understanding the formulation of this problem. Most examples I've found have clear expectations from the objective function and the target of the optimization typically does not have many possible matches that are defined by another variable.

Some info on the problem:

- Objective is to minimize the number of creates needed to satisfy modeltype required number
- Each crate contains any number (from 0-1000s) of modeltypes
- Each modeltype has a required number to meet from any number of crates
  ...... for example, if 10 modeltpyes are required, the optimization may get all 10 from one crate or 2 from one crate and 8 from another crate.
- There are many crates, but we do not need every create

I think what's throwing me off on this one is I can't approach it like the traditional optimization problems I've done in the past, where a modeltype would be assigned to 1 crate.

1. is this even a linear problem?
2. how can I think about the objective function?
3. are there even *really* any constraints? I suppose an artificial constraint would be to limit the number of creates that a modeltype could be searched in.
4. is this actually a very easy problem with an easy solution and I'm overcomplicating this?

Here's an example of modeltype and the number required.

| ModelTpye | Required # |
| --- | --- |
| model1 | 10 |
| model2 | 25 |
| ... | ... |
| model150 | 100 |

Here's the example of the crates and relationship to modeltype.

| Crate | ModelType | # of ModelType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | model1 | 10 |
| b | model1 | 5 |
| a | model2 | 17 |
| c | model2 | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| z | model50 | 5 |

I could list some of my PuLP code, but I feel like there may be a simple solution here that I simply have not thought of.

I tried to fit this in the bounds of a normal optimization problem, but to no avail. I keep getting stuck on the fact that the Modeltypes can be assigned to any number of bins subject to their requirements.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Edit****

Here's what I have so far for the logic. This returns an answer, but not the most efficient possible...

```
modeltypes= list(df['modeltype_id'])
crates= list(df['crate_id'])

problem = LpProblem("Minimize_Crates_Problem", LpMinimize)

modeltype_units_required = dict(zip(modeltypes, df['num_units_required']))

# gets the possible crates for each modeltype
modeltype_crates= {}
for m in modeltypes:
    modeltype_crates[m] = list(df[df["modeltype_id"] == m].crate_id)
    

#dictiomary within dictionary, modeltpye - crate- number of modeltype units in crate
modeltype_crate_units = {}
crate_units = {}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
for m in modeltype_crates:
  crate_units = {}
  for c in modeltype_crates[m]:
      temp_df = df[(df["modeltype_id"]==m)&(df["crate_id"]==c)]
      new_value = list(temp_df.units)[0]
      if new_value !=0:
        crate_units[c] = new_value
        modeltype_crate_units[m] = crate_units
    
    
# each modeltype can change crate to assign to
crate_pick = LpVariable.dicts('crate_pick', indices=[(m,c) for m in modeltypes for c in crates], cat='Binary')

# assigns modetype to 1 crate, since I wasn't sure how to allow it to assign to 1 or more crates
for m in modeltypes:
    problem += lpSum(crate_pick[m, c] for c in modeltype_crates[m]) ==1
    

# I think this means that a modeltype can only be assigned to a crate that has the number of units needed or higher
for m in modeltypes:
    problem += lpSum(crate_pick[m,c]*modeltype_crates_total[m][c] for c in modeltype_crates[m]) >= modeltype_units_required[m]
```

Answer (score 1):

The step from an English description to Python/Pulp code is often a bit too large. The best thing for me is to formulate a precise and compact mathematical model. Once we have that, transcribing this into Pulp is usually trivial. So here is my model:

```
  Data
      Demand[m]      "demand for model types"
      Content[c,m]   "number of items of type m in crate c"

  Binary Variables
      Use[c]     "usage of crates"

  Optimization Model
       min sum(c,Use[c])
           sum(c,Use[c]*Content[c,m]) >= Demand[m] for all m
```

If there are multiple crates of type a,b,.. then `Use[c]` should be an integer variable (with an appropriate upper bound).

Comment: thanks for your response. So the crates can have multiple types of modeltypes in them at the same time. How would that impact what you said?  Also, I have the dictionaries demand[m] and a nested dictionary Content[c,m], and I think I have the Use[c]? It's basically a binary lPvariable dict from a list comprehension. What would the syntax for the Optimization model look like in this case?

Comment: *So the crates can have multiple types of modeltypes in them at the same time.* Yes, that is why `Content[c,m]` has two indices. You can use dicts (or lists, arrays) to implement this. Choose your favorite indexing mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So when you say sum(c,Use[c]) what you really mean is problem += lpsum(c for c in Use[c]), and for  sum(c,Use[c]*Content[c,m]) >= Demand[m] for all m, you mean: for m in modeltypes: problem += lpsum(c for c in Use[c]*Content[c,m]) >= Demand[m]. How far off am I?

Comment: That does not look like valid Python to me.

Comment: That was my bad. I added my code to the page- it returns an answer and assigns all the modeltypes to a crate, but it's not the most efficient. Also, it currently does not allow a given modeltype to be assigned to multiple crates, only 1 at the moment for simplicity. How can I improve upon this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (2) Your code does not implement the mathematical model I suggested. I suspect that is intentional.

Comment: This works when "use" is binary, but does not when "use"
is integer, as listed here. Does this look similar to the mathematical model?              use = LpVariable.dicts('use', indices=crates, lowBound = 0, upBound = 3, cat = 'Integer'),     problem+=lpSum(use[c] for c in crates),    problem+=lpSum(use[c]*content[m][c] for c in modeltype_crates[m]) >= demand[m]

Comment: Difficult to read this way. Surely a `for m` loop is missing. If you can't figure it out, post a question with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I have a grasp, but would appreciate your help here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74869783/pulp-optimization-problem-fitting-items-into-crates-with-restrictions