# PuLP Optimization Problem: fitting items into crates with restrictions

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I would like some assistance with an optimization problem in Python..

Here is some background:

- Objective is to minimize the number of Crates (c) needed while satisfying Unit_ids (u) needed.
- Each crate contains any number (from 0-inf) number of different types of Units, with varying amounts to each
- Each Unit_id has a required demand to meet from any number of Crates ...... for example, if 10 items of Unit_id 123 are required, we may get all 10 from Crate A, or 2 from Crate X and 8 from crate Z. The choice of crate for 10 items of Unit_ID 123 depends on how many other Unit_ids are present in crate A vs X and Z.
- There are many crates, but we do not need every Crate

```
Definitions:
Crates -> list of all crate_ids

Units -> list of all unit_ids

Unit_crates[u] -> keys are unit_ids, values are list of crates that contain unit u

Demand[u] -> keys are unit_ids, values are number units of demand required

Content[u][c] -> dictionary within dictionary, the number of a type of unit_id in a crate c



Code:

from pulp import *
import pandas as pd

Crates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Units = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
Unit_crates = {'a': [1, 5], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4],  'd': [2, 3, 4]}
Demand = { 'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 4}
Content = pd.DataFrame({'unit_id':['a','b','c','b','c','d','c','d','c','d','a'],'crate_id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],  'content':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5,1,2,3]})
Content=(Content.groupby(['unit_id','crate_id']).agg(int).unstack(0).droplevel(0,1).agg(lambda x:dict(x.dropna())).to_dict())


Problem = LpProblem("Minimize_Number_of_Crates", LpMinimize)

Use = LpVariable.dicts('use', Crates, cat = 'Integer') 

Problem += lpSum(Use[c] for c in Crates) 

for u in Units:
   Problem += lpSum(Use[c] * Content[u][c] for c in Unit_crates[u]) >= Demand[u]

Problem.solve()
...
```

It's hard to tell if this actually fucntions as intended. Also, this only works for assigning 1 unit_id to one crate_id... It cannot assign 1 unit_id to multiple crates, which may or may not be another valid way of assigning units to crates.

Comment: Missing data, imports etc. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added some example data and imports. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues:

1. Always check the problem status

   ```
   print(f'Status: {LpStatus[Problem.status]}')
   ```
2. Printing the solution is missing

   ```
   for c in Crates:
       v = value(Use[c])
       if v > 0.5: print(f'crate type {c}: {v}')
   ```
3. `Use` should be non-negative:

   ```
    Use = LpVariable.dicts('use',  Crates, lowBound = 0, cat = 'Integer')
   ```

This will show:

```
Status: Optimal
crate type 2: 1.0
crate type 3: 1.0
crate type 5: 1.0
```

Note that this solution is not unique. However, it is guaranteed there is no solution with fewer crates being used.

Here is a picture showing typical behavior of a MIP solver.

[image]

Here I used random data (400 units, 4000 crates). We see that the optimal solution was already found after 124 seconds. The rest of the time (up to 1644 seconds) was used to prove optimality (the blue line stays flat at 30). In practice, we could have stopped much earlier. Note: the big jump at the end for the red line is because the solver knows the objective jumps by 1 (all cost coefficients are 1). This property is exploited here. The solver has proven optimality when the red line and blue line meet.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I did have another question, how can we view to see what the breakout of Units are in each Crate?  This would be a linear combination of Crates for each Unit Id, but I'm not sure how to extract this information out of the results without building it from scratch? Thanks again

Comment: That is not in the model. The model only provides the crates to be used. You can parcel out units from the crates any way you want (in general, there will be some leftovers).

Comment: Is there a optimal way to do that?    Secondly, what does it mean when v<.5? What does the value of v represent, and how does that translate to Units?

Comment: Basically, it's hard to understand the results unless v=1 or 0. Since v=.27 or v=.8 doesn't really translate to how much of the Crate to use, and how many units from a crate, if that makes sense.

Comment: v will be integer or close. For technical reasons, it can be 0.999999 or 2.00000001. So I can not say: `if v>=1`.  My `v >= 0.5` is a bit silly, but it is safe. Another approach would be to round v.

Comment: Of course v can be larger than 1, e.g. 2,3,4,.... (you did not specify an upperbound on how many crates you have of each type).

Comment: The idea is that there are 5 crates with varying amounts of the types of units. We should either use a crate or not, in order to fulfil the requirements of the unit demand. I added the upper bound a =1 in Units to try and prevent this, but I keep getting v values higher than 1. If I want to use a crate or not, should that mean v is equal to 1 or 0, or just >0?

Comment: For example, if I add another Unit 'z' with demand = 2, and then add content from crate '5' = 1 ,  I obviously get an infeasible solution because it is impossible to assign unit 'z' anywhere. But in this solutions, I get v= 1.5 and v=2 for a few crates. It's as if it ignores the binary 1/0 bounds in Unit

Comment: If infeasible the solution is bogus. Only trust the solution if it is optimal.

Comment: If you only have 1 crate for each type you should tell the solver that. So either use binary variables or integer variables with bounds 0 and 1.

Comment: I think at this point, the way it's set up is correct, but for some reason I keep getting infeasible solutions with my true dataset. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: You can easily check feasibility in advance. Make sure that `sum(c, Content[u][c]) >= Demand[u]`. If not, report which u is short and don't even try to optimize the number of crates.

Comment: Nice, thank you. My real dataset has about 750 Units and 8500 crates, and each unit is present in anywhere from 1-25 crates. It's been ruining for 3 hours at this point- hopefully it finishes soon. Otherwise, have any ideas on how I can improve this to make it more efficient?

Comment: I usually look at (1) better solvers (2) better formulations (3) short cuts (may be stop on a time-limit after finding a good solution) (4) faster hardware. I usually spent a lot of time trying to get better performance.

Comment: I have a thought, I could restrict the number of allowable Crates that a given Unit is "assigned" to. Right now, the optimization is probably checking every possible outcome of Units and the breakout of Crates they could fit into. Where would I add this constraint?

Comment: Something like this?        for u in Units:
   Problem += lpSum(Use[c] for c in Unit_crates[u]) <= 5

Comment: I don't think that will help much. My observation is that for these large instances a MIP solver finds the optimal or a good solution rather quickly (few minutes), but it cannot prove optimality quickly. The best is to add a time limit of say, 5 or 10 minutes and accept the best solution so far.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you share the syntax for stopping early? Thanks

Comment: See: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html

Comment: Hello once again- so I had the pulp.solve running for about 5 days and it still did not finish. I'm wondering if I should add some restrictions to the amounts of crates that a given unit can fit into. My intuition is that the model was probably running through every combinations of 1 of 20 necessary units being in all separate crates, for each unit, for all combinations of units. So, thinking I need either a constraint or "reward" for the objective function to try to minimize the crates needed while also reducing the number of crates a given unit can be picked across. Thought on this?

Comment: Study the solver log. That shows the progress of the lower and upper bound of the obj. Often the solver has found a very good solution or even optimal one very early in the search. It just cannot prove optimality. Many large practical problems are not solved to proven optimality. You may be able to preprocess the data and remove useless crates and may be combine similar ones. A high-end commercial solver may also do much better.

Comment: I added a picture of what I see when I solve a problem with 400 units, 4000 crates.